# R looping over two vectors

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I have created two vectors in R, using statistical distributions to build the vectors.

The first is a vector of locations on a string of length 1000. That vector has around 10 values and is called mu.

The second vector is a list of numbers, each one representing the number of features at each location mentioned above. This vector is called N.

What I need to do is generate a random distribution for all features (N) at each location (mu)

After some fiddling around, I found that this code works correctly:

```
for (i in 1:length(mu)){
a <- rnorm(N[i],mu[i],20)
feature.location <- c(feature.location,a)
}
```

This produces the right output - a list of numbers of length sum(N), and each number is a location figure which correlates with the data in mu.

I found that this only worked when I used concatenate to get the values into a vector.

My question is; why does this code work? How does R know to loop sum(N) times but for each position in mu? What role does concatenate play here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try and answer your question directly, `c(...)` is not "concatenate", it's "combine". That is, it combines it's argument list into a vector. So `c(1,2,3)` is a vector with 3 elements.

Also, `rnorm(n,mu,sigma)` is a function that returns a vector of `n` random numbers sampled from the normal distribution. So at each iteration, `i`,

```
a <- rnorm(N[i],mu[i],20)
```

creates a vector `a` containing `N[i]` random numbers sampled from `Normal(mu[i],20)`. Then

```
feature.location <- c(feature.location,a)
```

adds the elements of that vector to the vector from the previous iteration. So at the end, you have a vector with `sum(N[i])` elements.

Comment: Of course, I see; it works because it is a property of the rnorm function, in short. The combine argument simply ensures that the results from each round of iteration are stored somewhere before the loop recommences. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're sampling from a series of locations, each a variable no. of times. 
I'm guessing your data looks something like this:

```
set.seed(1) # make reproducible
N <- ceiling(10*runif(10)) 
mu <- sample(seq(1000), 10) 
> N;mu
 [1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1
 [1] 206 177 686 383 767 496 714 985 377 771
```

Now you want to take a sample from rnorm of length `N(i)`, with mean `mu(i)` and `sd=20` and store all the results in a vector. 
The method you're using (growing the vector) is not recommended as it will be re-copied in memory each time an element is added. (See [Circle 2](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), although for small examples like this, it's not so important.) 
First, initialize the storage vector:

```
f.l <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(mu)){
    a <- rnorm(n=N[i], mean=mu[i], sd=20)
    f.l <- c(f.l, a)
}
```

Then, each time, `a` stores your sample of length `N[i]` and `c()` *combines* it with the existing `f.l` by adding it to the end.

A more efficient approach is

```
unlist(mapply(rnorm, N, mu, MoreArgs=list(sd=20)))
```

Which vectorizes the loop. `Unlist` is used as `mapply` returns a list of vectors of varying lengths.

Comment: Good suggestions, thank you, particularly for the vectorization example. Vectorization is one thing that I want to master because it makes code much more elegant and efficient.